# Unbound prefix in first line of the Manifest

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I don't know much about the Manifest file.
All but the `uses-permission` line was computer-generated with the AIDE mobile IDE.

It was working fine before.
I think I must have accidentally deleted something.
Now it is saying there is an "unbound prefix" on the first line.
I've gone through other answers on here, though, and all XML manifests seem to have the exact same first line as I do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp" > 

    <application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> 

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Move the `<uses-permission ... />` line to above `<application>`, and then change that to `<application`. That is, remove the `>` there.

Comment: @MikeM. Seems like a reasonable answer

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, but I'd wanna put the fully-corrected XML in the answer, and I'm too lazy to copy/paste all that while I'm on a phone. :-) You're more than welcome to it.

Comment: Ya that did it! Thanks a lot. If you care to care to change your comment to an answer I can accept it. (Edit: posted this before refreshing the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a corrected Manifest for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp" > 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" /> 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```